# Online payment in us

Tags: payment, online

How to pay online to Amazon when name on the card is not mentioned in my Thomas cook forex card?

I tried to make a online payment, but it asks for my name on card which is not mentioned in my card and hance I am not able to make the payment

Comment: Is your Thomas Cook Forex card a credit or debit card? If not then you probably can't use it.

Comment: Just put your name in. There's no actual verification of the name field in the vast majority of cases (there's no cardholder name field in [the standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8583)), and [the card](https://www.thomascook.com/extras/travel-money-card) appears to be a Mastercard.

Comment: You could just write "no name on card" or write your actual name and see what happens. My card has a variation of my real name and I've never had a problem entering either version.